# Automating a code to use Map function, using it to plot with ListLinePlot command and plotting with certain imposed conditon

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, map

I have a code which goes like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
tbl = Table[{x, N[x^0.6], N[Sqrt[x]], N[x^0.2], N[x^(1/3)]}, {x, 0, 2,
     0.01}];
const1 = 20;
const2 = 15;
modifiedr[v_, k_] := (k - v) const1/const2 ;
newrow[{k_, r1_, r2_, r3_, r4_}] := {k, r1, modifiedr[r1, k], r2, 
   modifiedr[r2, k], r3, modifiedr[r3, k], r4, modifiedr[r4, k]};
newtbl = Map[newrow, tbl];
headings = 
  Flatten[{"k", 
    Table[str = ToString[i]; {"r" <> str, "modified_r" <> str}, {i, 1,
       4}]}];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["file" <> ToString[const1] <> ".dat", 
  Join[{headings}, newtbl]];
```

Here comes the first question:

1. You can see that there is line in the code    `{k,r1,modifiedr[r1,k],r2,modifiedr[r2,k],r3,modifiedr[r3,k],r4,modifiedr[r4,k]}`.This is okay when you have only 4 r’s (`r1,r2,r3,r4`). But when you have large no. of r’s, say till 20 (`r1,r2,r3, …, r20`), this can become tedious. Is there any way to automate this procedure just like what I have written in “headings”?

Now, I want to plot some graphs with x axis as first column in “newtbl” and second, fourth, sixth and eight columns in “newtbl” as y axis. For this one, I first extracted data into xaxis,yaxis1,yaxis2,yaxis3,yaxis4. For this, I wrote the following code:

```
rowlength = Length[newtbl];
xaxis = Table[newtbl[[i, 1]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
yaxis1 = Table[newtbl[[i, 2]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
yaxis2 = Table[newtbl[[i, 4]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
yaxis3 = Table[newtbl[[i, 6]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
yaxis4 = Table[newtbl[[i, 8]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{xaxis, #}] & /@ {yaxis1, yaxis2, yaxis3, yaxis4}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k\[Rho]", "\[Omega]"}]
```

I get desired plot as shown;

[image: Correct Expected Figure]

Second question comes here:

2. Extracting and writing `xaxis,yaxis1` etc. becomes tedious if I have large no. of r’s. Is there a way of getting around this issue?
   I modified the code according to what was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144428/how-to-specify-x-axis-in-list-when-using-mathematicia-and-listplot), i.e.
   `ListLinePlot[Transpose[Table[Map[{newtbl[[i, 1]], #} &, Rest[newtbl[[i]]]], {i,    Length[newtbl]}]]]` **and** `ListLinePlot[Thread[Thread@{#, {##2}} & @@@ newtbl]]`. But while doing in both ways I am getting a plot, which is showing extra set of lines:

[image: Wrong figure]

What am I doing wrong here and first of all, what does indeed the above code means?

Third question is this:

3. Now, I want to plot the with certain condition imposed. e.g.:

   a. plot r1 when modified_r1 has a value between 0.2 to 0.4

   b. plot r2 when modified_r2 has a value between 0.23 to 0.33

   c. plot r3 when modified_r3 has a value between 0.34 to 0.45

   d. plot r4 when modified_r4 has a value between 0.54 to 0.63

   How can I do this?

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1) you can define `newrow` to take a list of arbitrary length as input:

```
ClearAll[newrow2]
newrow2[x_List] := Flatten@MapAt[{#, (x[[1]] - #) const1/const2} &, x, {2 ;;}]

newrow2[Array[y, 5]]
```

> {y[1], y[2], 4/3 (y[1] - y[2]), y[3], 4/3 (y[1] - y[3]), y[4], 
>        4/3 (y[1] - y[4]), y[5], 4/3 (y[1] - y[5])}

This is the same as the output from your `newrow`:

```
newrow2[Array[y, 5]] == newrow[Array[y, 5]]
```

> True

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[newrow3]
newrow3[x_List] :=  Module[{xx = x}, 
  xx[[2 ;;]] = Transpose[{xx[[2 ;;]], (const1/const2) (xx[[1]] - xx[[ 2 ;;]])}]; 
  Flatten@xx]

newrow3[Array[y, 5]] == newrow[Array[y, 5]]
```

> True

A better approach is to process the input table `tbl` in one step:

```
ClearAll[makeNewTbl]
makeNewTbl[t_] := Riffle[##, {3, -1, 2}] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{t, (const1/const2) (t[[All, 1]] - t[[ All, 2 ;;]])}] &;
```

This produces the OP's `newtbl`:

```
makeNewTbl[tbl] == newtbl
```

> True

Comment: Many thanks for providing various suggestion. But, could you please explain a bit, atleast first method? I am seeing those stuffs (especially MapAt , #) for the first time!

Comment: @sreerajt, `MapAt[foo, lst, {pos_1, pos_2, ..., pos_k}]` replaces the element `lst[[pos_i]]` with `foo[lst[[pos_i]]]`. See the examples in docs page [MapAt](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) .